# Does HTML preconnect work for future api request?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, networking

I'm trying to preconnect to reduce api request's initial SSL negotiation time.

But it still looks like the SSL negotiation + TLS handshake + DNS lookup occurs.

The requesting url is apis.example.com and origin is m.example.com

Doesn't the preconnect have effect on future api request?

[image]

Adding `<link rel="preconnect" href="apis.example.com" crossorigin>`, reduces initial connection time.